# Why Don't All Users Show Up in Users List?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.  Using GraphAPI I can get a full list of users and everything works fine, but when I try to manage the users at portal.azure.com, I don't see them all.  So I click load more.  Then I click it a few more times, eventually it gets to displaying 115 users, and there's no more "Load more" option.  But there are still plenty of users out there!  And if I search for them by guid, they show up.  Why aren't all the users displayed there?  Is there any way to display them all without exporting a spreadsheet?  Is this just a bug, or is there something more to it?

A suggestion was made to turn off preview features, but I don't think I have them turned on.  When I click "Preview Features" in the upper right side of the "All Users" section I see:
[image: Preview features not turned on]

Answer (score 1):

Click `Preview Features` are the top right of the Azure AD - Users menu, deselect `Enhanced User Management` preview. We are working to revert this.

Comment: I don't believe I have preview features turned on.  I don't see any options there (see my edit above).  But maybe I don't have the right permissions or something?  Not sure.

Comment: Can you search by users email?

Comment: I can from Graph API.  From the Users page I don't think I have that option.  It only seems to search by "Name' (which I assume is displayName) and guid.

Comment: Did you try typing the email in

Comment: Yes, I did.  Whether or not that works depends on how the user was registered, I think.  Users I registered with Graph API do not work when I type in their email address (no results).  But they still come up when I enter their object id guid.  Users registered in portal.azure.com do work by either email address or id.

Comment: In your post, add what the payload is when your create the user via Graph API